# Announce ROS master by zeroconf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I've got a robot that's supposed to be deployed and used in a very dynamic network. Thus it gets a different IP address everytime it is (re-)started. This robot however is also supposed to be controlled remotely. Part of its ROS stack is running on a different system. This system reliably needs to find the ROS master in the network and for this purpose, I assume, zeroconf is the best approach.

But I need to know how to configure everything. I couldn't find any tutorial, yet, and I suppose that some of you guys have already done something like this. I know there's a bunch of `ros-hydro-zeroconf...` packages. I've installed them and run a few of the examples. They work but I don't know how I integrate this stuff into my configuration.

Hence, I'd be really grateful if you could point me to the right direction, maybe a tutorial or something, or give me detailed advice on what I've got to do to set this up.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135956/announce-ros-master-by-zeroconf/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

If your target is Linux based, you can use `avahi-daemon` on it to advertise it on the network as `<hostname>.local` by default *(this can be modified by configuring the daemon)*. On the client side, you can then identify the target by its host name.

If you need the IP, the command `avahi-browse -artp | grep <hostname>.local` will output records providing details about the Avahi services published by the target, including one containing the IP. It is pretty easy to select and parse it thanks to `cut` and alike.

An alternative to the grep approach is to publish a service on the target side using `avahi-publish`. On the client side you can then use `avahi-browse -t <servicename> -p` which will limit the output records to the relevant ones.

This solution is independent from ROS and can be exploited in startup scripts, both on target an client sides. I've used it with success in a lot of various situations involving headless Linux based black boxes, including Raspberry ones.

Hope this helps

Regards, Eric

---

Originally posted by [epascual](https://answers.ros.org/users/20673/epascual/) with karma: 68 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5